# How to Build & Run a project using ATOM editor

Tags: java, atom-editor

I find ATOM is the good editor and it is platform independent. I am running atom in windows 7 machine and i have  a project developed in JAVA which i want to test by doing some modifications in the code.

However, i don't find how to run the test or build a project. Basically i want to build a jar file, but i don't see an option to build a project.

I have gone through the online recommendation that says, i have to download the package,however i don't see an find an the related package to download.

Comment: If you're doing Java development, you could you use Maven as build too, it makes the building process much easier and there's a maven plugin for Atom.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should know that Atom is not a good IDE for Java, and you're better of using something like Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA.

You can just build a jar file using the command line:

```
jar cf jar-file-name files
```

where `jar-file` is the path to the new jar file to be created and `files` is the list of files to be included in the jar.

To include a main class in the jar and make it runnable, create a file called "manifest.txt" with the following contents:

```
Main-Class: MyClass
```

where `MyClass` is the fully qualified main class name.

Then use the command

```
jar cfm jar-file manifest.txt files
```

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: Let me try this out.